# Packer.io Consistent user flow for VirtualBox and Production builders

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, digital-ocean, provisioning, packer

I have been using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) with a [VirtualBox builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox.html) to build [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) VMs and even custom iso builds for dedicated hardware, but as I started looking into sharing the scripts with a [DigitalOcean builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/digitalocean.html) I noticed an inconsistency.

Every example I could find online using [VirtualBox builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox.html) would always use a non root user to ssh into the box for configuration.  Here is the example given on the builder page for [virtualbox-iso](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html):

```
{
  "type": "virtualbox-iso",
  "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
  "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso",
  "iso_checksum": "769474248a3897f4865817446f9a4a53",
  "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
  "ssh_username": "packer",
  "ssh_password": "packer",
  "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
}
```

Notice how even the `shutdown_command` is adjusted for this by using `sudo` to elevate permissions to perform `shutdown`.

You would also need to modify the `execute_command` if you wanted to run a script with elevated privileges:

```
"execute_command": "echo '{{ user `my_user_pass` }}'|sudo -S sh '{{.Path}}'",
```

The opposite is true for every example I have found using the [digitalocean builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/digitalocean.html)

```
{
  "type": "digitalocean",
  "api_token": "YOUR API KEY",
  "image": "ubuntu-14-04-x64",
  "region": "nyc3",
  "size": "512mb",
  "ssh_username": "root"
}
```

This would make sense to me as I'm sure many of the cloud providers do not by default create a secondary user.  I know [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) allows you to add custom provisioning scripts/meta-data so one way to provide consistency here would be to use metadata to create a secondary non-root user.  I didn't like that approach, however, as it isn't cross platform among providers and the metadata is still available on the box after creation.

Wouldn't it be better to just use the root user for the [virtualbox-iso builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html)?

Most of the examples I have seen are with Ubuntu and thus use a [preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) file to automate the iso installation.  They also tend to hard code `vagrant` as the user and password in the file.

I figure it would be better to skip creation of the secondary user in the preseed file, set a temp password for the sudo user, and do all configuration in your scripts and wrap up by disabling the root password (and likely all passwords and opt for certificate authentication).  This allows you to create the secondary user with variables and consistently handle both environments.

Here are some of the relevant parts of the preseed:

```
### Account setup
# Skip creation of a root account (normal user account will be able to
# use sudo). The default is false; preseed this to true if you want to set
# a root password.
#d-i passwd/root-login boolean false
# Alternatively, to skip creation of a normal user account.
#d-i passwd/make-user boolean false

# Root password, either in clear text
#d-i passwd/root-password password r00tme
#d-i passwd/root-password-again password r00tme
# or encrypted using a crypt(3)  hash.
#d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password [crypt(3) hash]
```

I actually did find one example in the wild [here](https://blogs.library.ucsf.edu/ckm/2014/06/09/production-packer-passwords-securing-the-root-user/) that not only uses root login but also doesn't include that in the preseed file either by passing in the `boot_command`:

```
"passwd/root-password=\"{{user `root_password`}}\" passwd/root-password-again=\"{{user `root_password`}}\" ",
```

This would allow you to avoid putting your temp root pass in source code to avoid the off chance someone tries to use it to ssh into your machine while it is being provisioned.

Is there any down side to this approach?  I would be curious if anyone has some example packer setups for testing and production they can share.

Thanks!!